# ReCaptcha key issue.Unable to create key

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I am using Asp.Net.I need to use ReCaptcha in one of my pages.I am trying to create a key so that I can use the ReCaptcha.But I dont know what exactly is the issue , but I keep getting the error.Here are the images

[image: Step1][image: Error]

Can anybody help me.What could be the issue

Comment: They 'are having a problem processing your request. Please try again later.'

Comment: @RobertDondo I saw this issue on their forums as well and users were complaining that the same issue was persisting since 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/3e8f724eaa2addb5?pli=1

Check this out, they are currently having problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had this problem before. 
Had to get a global key and use that, I think, not sure though...
A bit awkward, anyway.